# How can we pass multiple urls in collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am creating a social networking application, in that am using Horizontal collection view cell displaying for post.

my requirements are,

1. I have 10 differnt url api but in that see (initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=0" ) if i increase start_limit then i can get another post details.
2. I need to pass this data at the time of viewdidload
3. but how can get this post data at the time of viewdidload and collectionView numberOfItemsInSection how can i declare this suggest any ideas

   ```
   if(indexPath.item==3)

   {

   NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=0"];

   //    NSLog(@"%@ ",post);

   NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

   NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:vblive/APIFiles/Services.php?"]]];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   //    NSLog(@"request is %@",request);

   [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
   [request setHTTPBody:postData];

   _myConnection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

   //    NSLog(@"%@",conn);

   if(_myConnection2)

   {

       NSLog(@"connction sucess");

   }

   else

   {

       NSLog(@"unsucess");

   }
   ```

}

Thanks

Sravan

Comment: can u explain me the first point

Comment: my main concerns is if user login to my application then it will be shows up to ten post like in facebook app we login then it will be shows up to some post exactly like this i need to implement in my project here am getting every post data or details with using 
start_limit

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try some thing like this
**1. create a tag or you can use variable like**

NSString *startLimitValue;

**2. Then Assign the startLimit value in View did load or where ever you want like**

startLimitValue=@"one"

**3 then use indexPath to assign Start limit value to different collection view cell**

You can use Tags for specific item also

then dynamically set the no of items using Count method

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

if(check your condtion)

{
return [yourObject count];

}

else

if(check your conditon)

{

return [yourObject count];

}

}

Comment: Hi am passing like this only if(indexPath.item==1){ NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=0"];} and if(indexPath.item==2){ NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=1"];}

Comment: can u paste the whole method ?

Comment: you look at this tutorial it might help you http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/

Comment: the above method u wrote in view did load am i right ?

Comment: no in - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: in - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 10;
}

Comment: the problem is in you have used index path to get the data but u have not used indexPath.row to display the data

Comment: and am mention in  if(indexPath.item==1){ NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=0"];} and if(indexPath.item==2){ NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=1"];} up am giving if(indexPath.item==10)

Comment: the problem is am mention numberOfItemsInSection as return 10 but i don't need this i need return value is dynametically

Comment: you have to specifically tell xcode which row should display what.. use indexPath.row inside the connection succeded if condition.

Comment: hey i have one doubt i need to incerement Star_limit value 0,1,2,...10 ok i can increment this using for loop..it is possible..?

Comment: i have added how to dynamically count your objects and retun the no of  items in section

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response is %@\n",responseText);
    NSData *datta= [[NSData alloc]initWithData:data];
    [datta base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *err;
    responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    NSLog(@"count response dict \n %lu",(unsigned long)responseDict.count);}

Comment: am getting response in  responseDict but i need to pass this count in numberOfItemsInSection how it is possible?

Comment: How can i increment using the loop plz provide any code ..?

Comment: create a method and write the code which u have written in connection did receive response... call the method from your no of items in section get the count

Comment: ok but if i created new method then NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; in that data will not uesd that time what can i do ?

Comment: declare response Text globally so that u can use it in all methods

Comment: but initWithData:data is use of undeclaed identifier 'data'

Answer (score -2):

I guess start limit has the integer value.

I would suggest for each view give the tag in collection view as 0 or 1 or 2....as the start limit values.

Then when user tap on item then using `initWithFormat` format the string using tag value of the item.

Comment: Yes start_limit  is contains Interger value like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: but how can i assign start_limit value into differnt collectionview cell

Comment: Ok then set the item.tag=0 or 1 or 2(indexPath.row is user for table view I dont know for UIcollection view). Then use the tag value of that item.

Comment: till now am using like this only but it is static i need to implent dynametically

Comment: am passing like this only if(indexPath.item==1){  NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=0"];}    and  if(indexPath.item==2){  NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=1"];}

Comment: Yes Thats why i m saying use the tag value. As u know what will be the start limit use that value for tag.

Comment: start limit it's coming from my server

Comment: svrushal one thing can u expalin me, am having api url in that acc_id=104 && method=getHomeContents && start_limit=1" this methods are there upto it's ok but how can give collectionView numberOfItemsInSection

Comment: i need dynametically dispaly my post based on start_limt count in collectionView numberOfItemsInSection method